# Assign pointer-to-pointer to a pointer to a pointer inside a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, void-pointers

I am editing someone else's code and trying to make sense of it. The function passes in a parameter `void **dst_val`. I am not great with pointers. I have looked at all of the remotely relevant posts on stack overflow and didn't find what I am looking for.

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct {
  u_int img_out_len;
  char *img_out_val;
} img_out;
```

I declare a pointer to a struct:

```
img_out *clnt_res;
```

and allocate memory for it.

Now, where I'm confused. I need to set `void **dst_val` to point to the `img_out_val` pointer inside the pointer to the struct, and I can't figure out the syntax. Why are these incorrect, and what is correct?

```
dst_val = (void *)(*clnt_res).img_out_val; //wrong

dst_val = (void **)clnt_res->img_out_val; //wrong
```

I should also note that `img_out_val` points to data for a binary file.

---

**Edit:**

Since the function passes in `void **dst_val`, I need that to point to the data for the binary when the function returns.

Comment: `void **` is not compatible with `img_out *`. So doing anything like that will invoke an undefined behavior.

Comment: sorry yes it is typdefed, I should have included that.

Answer (score 1):

If frslm's anser is not good enough, you could also try

```
&(void*)clnt_res->img_out_val;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `clnt_res->img_out_val` gives you a `char *`, you need to get the address of that (to end up with a `char **`) before casting it as a `void **`:

```
(void **)&clnt_res->img_out_val;
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The cast-to-`void **` part?

Comment: `void **` is not compatible with anything other than `void **`. Not to confuse with `void*`

Comment: Thanks Eugene, what would be the correct way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Meg As stated in my very first comment - you *can't* do this legally. What you can do is to assign it to `void*`. Can you have `dst_val` as `void *`? I think what you actually want to do here is `*dst_val = ....`. But I am not sure. You need to provide more code.

Comment: @Eugene Sh.: What exactly is undefined behavior? In C you can convert any data pointer to any other data pointer type. There's no undefined behavior in the conversion itself.

Comment: @Eugene Sh.: It doesn't matter. C language explicity permits converting *any* object pointer type to any other object pointer type by means of an explicit cast. The only difference for `void *` is that it does not require an explcit cast. The only concern here is the alignment requirements. It is normal to expect alignment requirements of `void *` and `char *` to be the same, which means that conversion of `char **` to `void **` should be prefectly valid.

Comment: @AnT Why that concern is not enough? Update.. damn.. it's hard to keep up with the updates...

Comment: @Eugene Sh.: It is enough to claim that the above expression *might* trigger undefined behavior on an exotic platform where alignment requirements of `void *` and `char *` are different. In my opinion, it would be to harsh to flat-out slap an "UB" label on this code. It is akin to claiming that `a / b` is "UB" just because `b` might be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had to call

```
void foo(void ** ppv);
```

then to get around any casting questions/issues do it like this:

```
{
  void * pv = &clnt_res->img_out_val;
  foo(&pv);
}
```

or even shorter:

```
{
  foo(&((void*){&clnt_res->img_out_val}));
}
```

Please note that the above `void*` does *not* indicate a cast but defines a compound literal of type `void*`.